# Add items from ListBox into another List

Tags: c#, listview

I am currently creating a Windows form in which you type in an Item name (txtName), Quantity (numberPicker), and Price (priceSetter). When clicking add this will then add this to your Shopping Basket.

This works but when I click on one of them to remove it, the last item is always the one which gets removed because it's data is last stored.

I have already created a class called `ShoppingCartItem` and a class called `MyShoppingCart`, as shown below.

```
public class ShoppingCartItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class MyShoppingCart
{
    public List<ShoppingCartItem> MyShoppingList = new List<ShoppingCartItem>();
}
```

My idea is that each time you add something into the Shopping basket it is added to the List `ShoppingCartItem`, which is then stored into the Shopping Basket List. Hopefully, this will then allow me to remove or modify any item which the user needs to.

If anybody knows how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use the `YourListBox.SelectedIndex` property (if I remember the syntax right) to know which item is selected, and then, based on that index, to delete from your container. By the way, provide every code in a [MCVE] so you get a better response.

Comment: @FirstStep Thanks, your syntax was right. Do you know how I would delete it from my container?

Comment: It depends on your container. What is your container? As I said, provide every needed code so we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

U can add new field into ur ShopingCartItem class to set and hold index (place) in the list, so u can use it when accessing item in MyShopingList[index] to remove it.